# Access - Calculated field (running average)

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to generate an Access database with information which is currently in endless sheets and tables in Excel.

I would like to know if there is any way to add a field to one table which is a calculation (average value) based on several other cells.
I need to calculate the running 6 months average value of another field which contains 1 value per month.

[image]

[image: excel image]

Hopefully the previous image shows what I mean.

What is the best approach to import this functionality into access?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate an Excel spreadsheet in an Access table?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't normally store a calculated field in Access, you would run a query that provides you the calculation on the fly.

Without seeing your data structure it is impossible to tell you how to calculate the answer you need, but you would need your data correctly normalised in order to make this simple.